# I need a way to choose the path were i want my documents to be saved, save the path and use it after

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I want to be able to save some docx my program is generating in my downloads folder or be able to choose in what folder I want to save them any recommendations, so I can choose the path to save it and then use it?.

Edit: Thanks for the recommendations I did add them to the project, and sorry for being vague about what I'm looking for, so what I want is the user to be able to choose where to save the docs like the popup screen where you can choose the folder, so I can save the path and use it.

This is what I was using to browse folders and get the path to the folder I wanted to save my docs, it crashes the server when I use it.

```
string selectedPath;
string dirtemp;

var t = new Thread((ThreadStart)(() => {
                FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                fbd.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
                fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                    return;

                selectedPath = fbd.SelectedPath;
                if (!Directory.Exists(dirtemp))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirtemp);
                }
            }));
```

Comment: Hey Francisco, we generally need more details. For example, what have you tried? Do you have a database or api that you're connecting your Asp.net site to? If you're just trying to understand how to store user input from your website I'm sure there are a number of tutorials that could walk you through that.

Comment: @MikeParkhill I used a FolderBrowserDialog, and it worked fine locally, but when I published and uploaded the program it completely crashed the site, right now I'm using `string ub1 = "C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Downloads";` to save the user and use that path to save the files when they are generated, but when I upload it, it uses the server UserName instead of the users.

Comment: First, you should not concatenate your strings like that. Second, dynamically build your path and use the executable when you deploy: Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

Answer (score 0):

it really much up to you.

Remember, when you use URL's (web) with asp.net, then you ALWAYS use a vaild URL.

but, in code behind? You use full plain jane windows path names.

so, you can quite much use any folder on your system - as long as that folder is given rights. So you can use a low cost SAN or some other computer on the nextwork.

Now for users to get those files?
You have two choices:

You use code behind to grab and then steam down the PDF file or whatever. In this case, users can NEVER type in a vaild URL, since that folder is NOT part of your root wwww web folder.

However, often you do want URL's to be valid (say for pictures), or even allowing customers to get documents they want.

So, in IIS configuration, you can add what is called a virtual foler.

So that other computer might be say:

```
\\someserveronnetwork\pdfdocs\
```

And then you can add what is called a virutal folder to the web site that MAPS to the above folder that is not even part of the www root folders, and in fact does not even have to be on the same server.

And you can choose any name. So we could map above folder to

MyPdfDocuments.

Now, a valid URL would be:

```
http://www.mywebsite/MyPdfDocuments/policy.pdf.
```

If you do this:

```
debug.print Server.MapPath("above url")

you get: \\\\someserveronnetwork\pdfdocs\policy.pdf
```

so your code behind AWAYS uses valid window path names. And MapPath will convert the full URL to that path name.

You can of course just create + include a folder in your current web site (a folder in wwwroot, and again valid URL's will work.

but, as noted, you can choose to not have the folder in the web site. and you can choose to NOT map the folder (a virtual folder) that is say on some other computer on the same network.

In this case, then no valid URL's ever exist, and the only way to dish out a file to a user is to provide some web page - perhaps driven by a database, and when a user requests a file, the code behind grabs the file and streams it out to the user. This setup of course is more secure, since any PDF, Excel document etc. NEVER really exists as a valid URL, and the only way to get that file is for code behind to directly read that file and stream it out to the end user.

So, if security not a issue, and you want a valid URL? Then by using what is called a virtual folder, then any legal folder on your network can be mapped to that virtual folder, and as a result any valid URL typed in can fetch/see those documents in that folder.

So the best choice? It will depend on your needs - but the above covers your possible options - and you can pick either road based on your needs.